# ArcGIS online widgets - filter by attribute

Tags: arcgis-online, filter, widget

I started to use ArcGIS online. I created my map and I published it as a web app. I would like to ask if there is any possibility to allow users to filter by attributes using widgets or so on? I can't find this option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Filter Widget and create your own expressions for the users to choose from alternatively you can use the Query Widget to allow users to query specific layers/data

http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-query.htm